# Integrating Cameyo and Jenkins unittests: Is there a way to propagate exit codes out to the host shell in cameyo?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, virtualization, automated-tests

I am attempting to virtualize an app we are developing using cameyo.  To confirm testing I need to run our unittests within the virtualized environment.  Running of the tests is not a problem.  I can run the tests (using app.cameyo.exe -exec "command") and see the result.  However, when the cameyo app executes the tests and returns the exit code is 0 (success) no matter what the result of the tests.  I assume this is because according to Cameyo the command virtualized environment ran the command and quit without any problem with the virtualization process (even though the exit code of the app itself would be non-zero).  Here is the cameyo commandline I am using:

C:\Cameyo\apps\app.cameyo.exe -exec nosetests.exe %WORKSPACE%

(without %WORKSPACE% does the same thing because everything runs from the workspace in jenkins by default)

So, the tests run, but the return from the .cameyo.exe app is always successful.  Is there a way to propagate the exit code of the virtualized application out to the host command line so that we can get a failure code when the tests fail?

ps I expect this would be applicable to other unittest frameworks and other virtualization platforms.  Also, I tried to add cameyo as a tag, but not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Add -wait before your -exec command:
C:\Cameyo\apps\app.cameyo.exe **-wait** -exec nosetests.exe %WORKSPACE%